# Tokenization of text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, replace, tokenize

I have a neat challenge and can't complete it with myself!

To everyone who don't know what tokenization is, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization

**Goal**

Process text word-for-word and then replace it with another word.

**Text input example**

> I may have **HTML** and I am gonna be replaced.

**Text output example**

> I can have **XHTML** but I need to be renewed.

What I need are tips on how to process word-for-word with jQuery. If it needs it: with Tokenization, I stumbled upon that. It could be a solution, maybe not.

**Edit:**
A simple replace function did not help me because it replaces all occurrences of the word in the whole text at once.

**Edit2:**
Matt asked me for the code I had written and did not work, here it is:

```
$("#textarea").replace(/\bword\b/g, 'replacedword');
```

Comment: I tried several implementations such as the replace functionality of jQuery. But that does not help me because the word I want to process can be multiple times in the text and gets replaced too. That is not what I want. I need it to be word-for-word.

Comment: Post the code you did try, and explain why it doesn't work. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var words = text.split(/(\s|\n|\t)+/g)` ...now you have an array of words that you can iterate on, replace certain words.
You can remake the text by  joining the array : `words.join(' ')`.
This is done without the help of jquery.

Does this help?